# Why does Facebook crop my image in shared post?

Tags: facebook, sharing

According to Facebook's Webmaster docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/images/), if an image in a post is smaller than 600 x 315, it still should be displayed in a rectangular shape. But when I post a picture that's 382 x 200, it gets cropped to a square shape.

Where are the docs explaining this behavior? How can I prevent this cropping?

Comment: Didn't you just link to the documentation?  It says "Use images that are at least 1200 x 630 pixels" and you won't have any problems.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, yes, but I need small picture as in example in docs.

Comment: My guess is that they changed the way it works without updating the documentation.  Most sites want to get the large images.